# Writing line by line to file with c

Tags: c, file, file-io

I have a question about writing words to a file. It is wanted that a word coming from a file will be written to an intermediate file named as temp2-i. Here i changes according to the word length.

Here is my code:

```
 while(!feof(args->file))
{
    if(EOF!=fscanf(args->file,"%s",word))
    {
        //create intermediate file name as tempj-i
        sprintf(str, "%d", j);
        sprintf(str2 , "%d" , i);

        strcpy(result , "temp");
        strcat(result, str);
        strcat(result , "-");
        strcat(result, str2);

        //create intermediate file
        destFile = fopen(result , "w"); --> here is problem
        if (destFile== NULL) {
            printf("Error in opening a file..", destFile);
        }

        fprintf(destFile , "%s", word);
        fprintf(destFile ,"%s" , " ");

        fclose(destFile);
        count++;


    }
}

  fclose(args->file);
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

My question is even if there are many words to be written to the same intermediate file , at the end only one of them is written. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: file open mode "w" --> "a".

Comment: and `sprintf(result, "temp%d-%d", j, i);`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are opening the file each time through the loop.  Presumably you want to open it just once, outside the loop, and write to it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the file for each individual word separately. If this is intentional (why?) you would have to use "wa" as the open mode. If this is not intentional you should open the file outside the loop, and close it when the loop exits.

```
destFile = fopen(result , "w"); --> here is problem
```

must be

```
destFile = fopen(result , "wa");
```

This will cause the writing to go to the end of the file before writing, appending your new data.

Comment: But as I have said , each word coming from same file is written to seperate files. How can I specify which file should be written without opening it by giving name to it??

Comment: But I am saying that intermediate file name will change according to the word length , so first I must take the word then I must find the length and must create the file name according to this information. Thus , I must create file name in the while(...) to take the length of each word. What can I do?

Comment: Updated my answer. I already said in the beginning that "wa" must be use in that case.

Comment: Okey I have changed to wa but result did not change. Again at the end there is only one word written..:(

Comment: Did you debug it and see what is in `words`?

Comment: Yes I know what the result file should look like , I have calculated for every word the intermediate file.

Comment: You shall not calculate your code, you should debug it. Since you are only showing a snippet, how should anybody know what is wrong? Fire up a debugger and check what the code is really doing. Maybe your input file is wrong, or some other stuff.